# Getting input value after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, web

I have a table who's rows are generated from the database, and in each row there's a cell containing an input of type number, which I'm giving it as id like `{ id="quantity<?php echo $product->id ?>" }` so its stays unique.

I can successfully get the value in the first time ( before the ajax request that generates the table again from an another php page ) . But I try to get the value after ajax success but it gives me `undefined`.

```
$(".card2").delegate(".buy", "click", function() {
  var order = 1;
  var id = this.value;
  var quantity = $('#quantity' + id).val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "order.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      order: order,
      quantity: quantity,
      prodID: id
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('.card2').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

The data received from the ajax success is basically the whole table to be replaced in the div ".card2"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is an example of `this.value`? Does this change after the AJAX call? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: FYI, jQuery's `.delegate()` method has been deprecated. The replacement is to use `.on()`, eg `$('.card2').on('click', '.buy', function(e) { ... })`

Comment: Yeah i know its been replaced by on on the newer version ! thank you btw

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the entire table after the success call. You replace the div element with the returned data by using $('.card2').html(data); 
Inspect the returned 'data' and make sure you are including the same input button, id, handler, etc for the new table(in data) being rendered.

Comment: i did ! basically its the same table , copy and paste ! but i just doesn't get it and i don't know why ! it says undefined value